# TYPO3 9/10, tx_form hide label or add a css class

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

is there a possibility to add a css class to field labels? I need to hide labels of fields only visually. I found a possibility to add class names to the field itself or the container which contains the field but not the label or the container which contains label and field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default. But you can add a custom property to the desired field(s) in your form definition.

Form field labels are set globally in the Fluid partial "Field.html". This is convenient: we only need to adjust a single template to support all fields. Extend the label's class attribute with the condition below.

#### File "yourContactForm.form.yaml":

```
identifier: someTextField
label: 'Label, hidden but available to screen readers'
type: Text
properties:
  hideLabelVisually: 1
```

#### File "Partials/Field/Field.html":

```
<f:if condition="{doNotShowLabel} != 1">
  <label class="control-label {f:if(condition: element.properties.hideLabelVisually, then: ' visually-hidden')}"
  for="{element.uniqueIdentifier}">{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'label')}<f:if condition="{element.required}"><f:render partial="Field/Required" /></f:if></label>
</f:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. It does not work for me because i need it only for some individual fileds but good to know that it is possible to add classes for types of fields! I hav chosen a workaround: i add an additional class to the fields and let javaScript do the rest.

Comment: Just to clarify: this is not type-dependent. You can add the custom property "hideLabelVisually" in your form YAML where needed. Only then the "visually-hidden" class will be added for this particular field. All other fields are not affected.

Comment: Ciao @sebkln ... did something change for V11 ? It will not work for me in V11 (I mean 'hideLabelVisually' ... of course in the template is always valid)

Comment: TYPO3 v11 comes with two template variants (Bootstrap 4 and 5). If you use "templateVariant: version2", the corresponding "Field.html" partial will be different.