# TYPO3 Ext:Form tx_form hide all labels ... doNotShowLabel

Tags: yaml, typo3, typoscript

I would like to hide all labels and it seems to be doable with a declared variable `doNotShowLabel = 1` ... only that I cannot find where to include this to make it work.

(Of course did I already leave all labels blank, but the required fields display an `*` which is fairly ugly)

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349964/typo3-9-10-tx-form-hide-label-or-add-a-css-class) shows an appraoch, but it suggests the exact question that I'd like answered ... (the first comment of lisardo) I would like to keep the fluidtemplates untouched ...

Typo3 V11

Comment: From an accessibility point of view the labels should be available. If you do not want them to be displayed, I suggest to move them out of the viewport via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The `doNotShowLabel` is not configurable with yaml files by default and i did not find a way to do it without touching the fluid templates. I guess by default the variable is used for the internal call of the generic field template.

I am actually using Typo3 V12.3. I configured it to use template version2, because version1 is deprecated and will be removed in v13.

The default files for rendering the frontend for my environment are located in the folder `vendor/typo3/cms-form/Resources/Private/FrontendVersion2/`. You should not change them directly, i just do it for brevity.

The file `Partials/AdvancedPassword.html`contains

```
<f:render partial="Field/Field" arguments="{element: element, renderFieldset: '{element.properties.renderFieldset}', doNotShowLabel: 1}" contentAs="elementContent">
```

`doNotShowLabel` is not read from a yaml file, in this case it is hard coded for advanced password fields.

So, if you for example want to do hide the labels for standard text fields, you could change the following line in the file `Partials/Text.html` from

```
 <f:render partial="Field/Field" arguments="{element: element}" contentAs="elementContent">
```

to

```
<f:render partial="Field/Field" arguments="{element: element, doNotShowLabel: '{element.properties.doNotShowLabel}'}" contentAs="elementContent">
```

and update the yaml configuration to

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formElementsDefinition:
            Text:
              properties:
                doNotShowLabel: true
```

Comment: I upvoted because your information is very valid but ... I ended up adopting the solution of the quoted question, too elaborate to change every call to the partial